# Tensor Notation - David Tongs Notes

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, maxwell-equations, variational-calculus

I'm trying to understand the Maxwell's Equation example from David Tongs QFT notes. He uses the Lagrangian:
$$ 
L = -\frac{1}{2}(\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu})(\partial^{\mu}A^{\nu})+\frac{1}{2}(\partial_{\mu}A^{\mu})^2
$$
To compute the equations of motion. I understand the Einstein summation notation but I don't understand how one computes $
\frac{\partial{L}}{\partial(\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu})}$

Can someone explain to me the steps to compute:
$$
\frac{\partial{L}}{\partial(\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu})} = -\partial^{\mu}A^{\nu}+(\partial_{\rho}A^{\rho})\eta^{\mu\nu}
$$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Derivation of Maxwell's equations from field tensor lagrangian](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3005/)

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3005/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/64272/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/367920/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Can you show what you’ve tried and we can probably help you out?