# Is there a quick way to calculate the derivative of a quantity that uses Einstein's summation convention?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, special-relativity, field-theory, differentiation

Consider $F_{\mu\nu}=\partial_{\mu}A_\nu-\partial_\nu A_\mu$, I am trying to understand how to fast calculate $$\frac{\partial(F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu})}{\partial (\partial_\alpha A_\beta)}$$

without expanding the multiplication in terms of $A$. Clearly if we do not have indices, this can be done very quickly with a glance, yet when there are indices multiplication factors come into play we would, in this case get a factor of $4$ before usual derivative.

Is there a way to glance at it and get correct answer immediately?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3005/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The product rule (Leibniz rule) applies to functional derivatives, so we have
$$
\frac{\partial(F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu})}{\partial (\partial_\alpha A_\beta)} = 2 F^{\mu \nu} \frac{\partial(F_{\mu\nu})}{\partial (\partial_\alpha A_\beta)} = 2 F^{\mu \nu}\left( \delta^{\alpha}_{\mu} \delta^{\beta}_{\nu} - \delta^{\alpha}_{\nu} \delta^{\beta}_{\mu}\right) = 4 F^{\alpha \beta}.
$$
The step where I actually take the derivative of $F_{\mu \nu}$ with respect to $\partial_\alpha A_\beta$ does involve writing out the field strength in terms of the derivatives, but it's less complicated in this version.

Comment: Aren’t functional derivatives usually written with $\delta$ rather than $\partial$? Or is that old-fashioned? Are you just following the OP’s notation?

Comment: @Ghoster:  There are different schools of thought, I think.  My own style is to use $\delta$ for small variations when I'm doing calculus of variations problems *ab initio* and to use partial derivatives for functional derivatives.  It does overload the notation a bit but it's not usually a problem.